# Looking for an expression or idiom for a weak person who can be easily bullied or intimidated

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In my native language we have this expression for a weak person - " a low fence " implying that anybody can jump over it ( fig. humiliated or treated badly ) Is there a similar expression or idiom in meaning in English for this type of person ?

Answer (score 3):

I would describe someone like that as a ***pushover***.

> ***[pushover](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pushover)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. *informal* A person who is easy to overcome or influence.
>
>    *‘Colonel Moore was benevolent but no pushover’*

(From the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Huffington Post has an article about *[10 Signs You May Be a Pushover and What to Do About It](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/sherrie-campbell-phd/10-signs-you-may-be-pusho_b_8491442.html)* while Insider lists only *[7 signs you're the office pushover and not just a nice person](https://www.thisisinsider.com/how-to-tell-if-youre-a-pushover-or-just-nice-at-work-2018-4)*.

Answer (score 1):

**Doormat**

One who can be walked all over, or:

> 2. informal a person who offers little resistance to ill-treatment by others

From Collins vie [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Doormat)